# How do delegate/lambda typing and coercion work?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, type-inference, anonymous-methods

I've noticed some examples of things that work and don't work when dealing with lambda functions and anonymous delegates in C#.  What's going on here?

```
class Test : Control {
    void testInvoke() {
        // The best overloaded method match for 'Invoke' has some invalid arguments
        Invoke(doSomething);

        // Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type
        Invoke(delegate { doSomething(); });

        // OK
        Invoke((Action)doSomething);

        // OK
        Invoke((Action)delegate { doSomething(); });

        // Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type
        Invoke(() => doSomething());

        // OK
        Invoke((Action)(() => doSomething()));
    }

    void testQueueUserWorkItem() {
        // The best overloaded method match for 'QueueUserWorkItem' has some invalid arguments
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(doSomething);

        // OK
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { doSomething(); });

        // The best overloaded method match for 'QueueUserWorkItem' has some invalid arguments
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((Action)doSomething);

        // No overload for 'doSomething' matches delegate 'WaitCallback'
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)doSomething);

        // OK
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)delegate { doSomething(); });

        // Delegate 'WaitCallback' does not take '0' arguments
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => doSomething());

        // OK
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => doSomething());
    }

    void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Well that's a lot of examples.  I guess my questions are the following:

1. Why does `Invoke` always refuse a lambda function or an anonymous delegate, yet `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` does just fine?
2. What the heck does "Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type" mean anyway?
3. Why does `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` accept an anonymous delegate with no parameters, but not a lambda expression with no parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` has a *specific* delegate in its signature; Invoke just has `Delegate`. Lambda expressions and anonymous methods can only be converted to a specific delegate type.
2. It's just a bad error message. It means, "I don't know exactly which delegate type you're trying to convert to."
3. You're using an anonymous method *without a parameter list at all* which can be converted to any delegate type which doesn't use out/ref parameters. If you tried `delegate() { ... }` (i.e. an explicitly empty parameter list) then it wouldn't work. This "I don't care about parameters" ability of anonymous methods is the *only* feature they have which lambda expressions don't.

It's easiest to demonstrate all of this in the context of simple assignments, IMO:

```
// Doesn't work: no specific type
Delegate d = () => Console.WriteLine("Bang");

// Fine: we know the exact type to convert to
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("Yay");

// Doesn't work: EventHandler isn't parameterless; we've specified 0 parameters
EventHandler e1 = () => Console.WriteLine("Bang");
EventHandler e2 = delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Bang again"); };

// Works: we don't care about parameter lists
EventHandler e = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Lambdas can't do this"); };
```

Comment: And I thought I understood delegates and lambdas.  I was so foolish.

Comment: Good stuff as ever, +1 for "... is the only feature they have which lambda expressions don't."

Comment: @recursive, if you're interested to learn more, read up on expression trees.  The interesting thing about lambda expressions is that they really are _expressions_, with a rich descriptive model for what's being expressed, and not merely a syntactic shortcut for passing logic to a delegate parameter.  This is what allows magic like LINQ to SQL to happen. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: @Dan: Don't forget that statement lambdas are also lambda expressions, but can't be converted to expression trees. Lambda expressions themselves are neither expression trees nor delegates - they're just a piece of source code which can be converted to either.

Comment: true, I forget about statement lambdas.  It's amazing to me the kinds of things that can be expressed in the language these days.  We've come a long way from ANSI C.